# Show ContextMenu via ENTER key on selected row 2nd column in TableView (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, contextmenu, keypress

until now I have only managed to make the contextMenu appear within the frame of the 
TableView once I press the ENTER button with this code `contextMenu.show(tableView, Side.RIGHT, 0, 0);`. But this way the contextmenu pops up only in a static position.

### 1. Howto get x y position of selected row 2nd column

I would like the contextmenu appear dynamically, that is whenever the user press ENTER key on a selected row, the contextmenu will show in the **selected row on its 2nd column**: please look at the given picture below.[image]

Is there something like this

> contextMenu.show(tableView, x-SelectedRow2ndCol, y-SelectedRow2ndCol);

### 2. Howto Contextmenu shows wholly in visible area

For instance if the selected row is the last row of the TableView and thus its position is at the lowest part of the screen, still the contextmenu will pop up all its items above the last row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lookupAll` can be used to get all `TableRow`s from the `TableView`. Find the selected one and get the child `TableCell` with a `tableColumn` matching the column. This gets you the `TableCell`. Show the `ContextMenu` using the [`show(Node anchor, Side side, double dx, double dy)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ContextMenu.html#show-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.geometry.Side-double-double-) method. This also takes care of keeping the menu on screen.

From the javadoc:

> If there is not enough room, the menu is moved to the opposite side and the offset is not applied.

Example of a key listener on `TableView`:

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = ...

TableColumn secondColumn = tableView.getColumns().get(1);

tableView.setOnKeyReleased(evt -> {
    if (evt.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        Set<Node> rows = tableView.lookupAll(".table-row-cell");
        Optional<Cell> n = rows.stream().map(r -> (Cell) r).filter(Cell::isSelected).findFirst();

        if (n.isPresent()) {
            Optional<Node> node = n.get().getChildrenUnmodifiable().stream()
                    .filter(c -> c instanceof TableCell && ((TableCell) c).getTableColumn() == secondColumn)
                    .findFirst();

            if (node.isPresent()) {
                Node cell = node.get();
                Bounds b = cell.getLayoutBounds();
                contextMenu.show(cell, Side.BOTTOM, b.getWidth() / 2, b.getHeight() / -2);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Note that this doesn't work, if there is no selected table row visible.

Comment: Hi Fabian, thanks you so much for your answer! Your answer is a breeze to follow since it covers both the theory concisely and the FULL implementation in code. I am really blown away by the art of your solution. I also do appreciate you telling the restriction if no items were selected which shows the state of your mind - concise and responsible. The community must be grateful to have you by its side. Thank you!